# How to select a sub-dictionary given a condition

Tags: python, dictionary

```
mydict = {'a': {'name': 'Marco', 'gender': 'm', 'age': 38, 'info': 'teacher musician'}
          'b': {'name': 'Daniela', 'gender': 'f', 'age': 28, 'info': 'student music'}
          'c': {'name': 'Maria', 'gender': 'f', 'age': 25, 'info': 'doctor dance whatever'}}
```

How to select the records with an age below 30 and with the words including 'music' in the 'info'?
The results should be like:

```
newdict = {'b': {'name': 'Daniela', 'gender': 'f', 'age': 28, 'info': 'student music'}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplest way is to use a dict-comp:

```
mydict = {'a': {'name': 'Marco', 'gender': 'm', 'age': 38, 'info': 'teacher musician'},
          'b': {'name': 'Daniela', 'gender': 'f', 'age': 28, 'info': 'student music'},
          'c': {'name': 'Maria', 'gender': 'f', 'age': 25, 'info': 'doctor dance whatever'}}

new_dict = {k:v for k,v in mydict.iteritems() if v['age'] < 30 and 'music' in v['info'].split()}
# {'b': {'info': 'student music', 'gender': 'f', 'age': 28, 'name': 'Daniela'}}
```

Comment: @Franco it's short for *dictionary comprehension* - it builds a dictionary from another iterable with an optional `if` clause - which is where you put any additional conditions you want to apply

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following comprehension :

```
>>> {d:k for d,k in mydict.items() if k['age']<30 and 'music' in k['info']}
{'b': {'info': 'student music', 'gender': 'f', 'age': 28, 'name': 'Daniela'}}
```

`mydict.items()` give you a tuple contain key ans value of dictionary at each loop , and you can chose the item that have the proper conditions !